# Postgresql slow update for a new column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-update

I have a geography table in postgresql 9.3 with around 600k records

Other process use that table to get roads info, but not updates only select. So I think I can discard deadlock issues?

I create a new field, then I try to update that field and last for 30 min so I cancel query.

So I proced to recreate a new table add the new field and update it.
Then recreate the indexes, delete old table and rename the new one. Took around 2 min.

So even I solve the update I'm wondering  
Are the selects from the other tables locking my update? 
Or is because the indexes slow the update even when the new field doesnt have index yet?

Comment: PostgreSQL does create a new version of each record that you are updating, and you are updating all the records. These 2 urls throw a lot of light on your doubts- about updating non-indexed columns. http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/site/html/misc/hot.html    http://facility9.com/2011/04/postgresql-update-internals/  You can find out if something is locking the table, but chances are slim that is the reason. Especially as you said other sessions will only read from the table. Here is how to get lockinfo https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jayadevan 
The answer is UPDATE work like an INSERT plus DELETE.

That is why creating a new table is faster.